# Как обновить только одно значение в объекте в MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

В MongoDB есть объект такого вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим, его нужно обновить:

Запрос на обновление:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код внутри роута:

```js
await News.updateOne({ id: reqBody.id }, { $set: { content: reqBody.content } })
```

Но как итог в объекте в поле `content` содержит просто `"headline: "Новый заголовок". Как можно обновить только одно поле этого объекта?

Comment: Обновить нужно весь `content` или только одно его свойство `content.headline`?

Comment: @entithat, Только свойство

Comment: @entithat, но передавать я могу не только headline, но и другие свойства

Comment: Ну тогда надо конкретно указать какое поле менять, ведь сейчас монго думает так: ага, указано content, значит заменяю весь content значением из `reqBody.content`. Укажите что-то вроде: `"content.headline": reqBod.content.headline` и так для каждого ключа. Иначе никак.

Comment: Либо используйте https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-dot-notation, чтобы библиотека сама все за Вас сделала.